# Correspondence between chapters and Bekker numbers in Metaphysics

Tags: metaphysics, aristotle

Where can I find a table of correspondences such that if one work cites Aristotle's metaphysics by book and chapter, I can find the passage in an edition with Bekker numbers but no chapter divisions?

Comment: Usually editions have the 19a13 numbering.

Answer (score 1):

The general format to cite Aristotle's works using Bekker numbers is as follow (there may be some minor stylistic variations):

**[title,][book number.][chapter number,][page number][column letter][line number]**

Here, the definitive pointer is the Bekker number (except *Constitution of the Athenians* and the fragments):

**[page number][column letter][line number]**

since each work of Aristotle has a distinct starting Bekker number (see [the table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekker_numbering#Aristotle%27s_works_by_Bekker_numbers)). Thus, one should reckon that a citation to *Topics* falls between the Bekker numbers 100a and 164b (164b falls partly into *On Sophistical Refutations*) and vice versa. Notice that the column letter is either **a** or **b**.

Hence, one does not actually need a chapter number to find out the corresponding line in the Bekker edition. The publishment itself ought to provide enough information for the Bekker number (with a correspondence table, etc.). For example, the Loeb edition of Nicomachean Ethics indicates the correspondence on the right of the original text.

[image].

If no information is supplied, one has to find out the correspondence by checking out other sources. I recommend *The Complete Works: The Revised Oxford Translation*, edited by Jonathan Barnes, [volume 1](https://archive.org/details/completeworksofa0000aris) and [volume 2](https://archive.org/details/completeworksofa0002unse_z3o6).